# H2 Console starts on IP address which is not mine

Tags: h2

If I run

H2JAR=/common/home/jjs/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.3.168/h2-1.3.168.jar
java -cp $H2JAR org.h2.tools.Server $*

I get

```
Web Console server running at http://68.178.232.99:8082 (only local connections)
TCP server running at tcp://68.178.232.99:9092 (only local connections)
PG server running at pg://68.178.232.99:5435 (only local connections)
```

But I have

```
1004 ~\>traceroute 68.178.232.99
traceroute to 68.178.232.99 (68.178.232.99), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  190.33.189.161 (190.33.189.161)  9.145 ms  9.023 ms  9.467 ms
 2  172.31.36.254 (172.31.36.254)  171.169 ms  171.083 ms  170.976 ms   
 3  10.255.6.9 (10.255.6.9)  170.811 ms  170.641 ms  170.529 ms
 4  ge-0-0-0.bal1-int-1.jf1-agr-1.cwpanama.net (201.224.254.237)  170.416 ms  170.306 ms  170.193 ms
 5  so-7-1-3.mia11.ip4.tinet.net (216.221.158.49)  185.066 ms  186.763 ms  188.797 ms
 6  xe-2-2-0.mia10.ip4.tinet.net (89.149.184.254)  189.751 ms xe-8-0-0.mia10.ip4.tinet.net (89.149.180.185)  202.777 ms xe-1-0-0.mia10.ip4.tinet.net  (89.149.183.21)  202.611 ms
 7  ge-0-2-2.mpr2.mia1.us.above.net (64.125.13.81)  211.130 ms  215.839 ms  217.518 ms
 8  xe-4-0-0.cr2.iah1.us.above.net (64.125.30.202)  219.719 ms  221.003 ms  228.238 ms
 9  xe-1-1-0.mpr4.phx2.us.above.net (64.125.30.149)  219.337 ms  225.518 ms  228.868 ms
 10  209.66.64.6.t01121-04.above.net (209.66.64.6)  228.763 ms  214.909 ms  215.359 ms
```

my host file is:
    127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
    ::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

Answer (score 0):

H2 tries to detect the IP address of your computer. It seems it doesn't work correctly in your case. Could you run the network test of the H2 database? You would need to download the .zip file of H2, expand it, `chmod` the `build.sh` file, and then run:

```
./build.sh testNetwork
```

In my case the result is:

```
Target: testNetwork
localhost:
  localhost/127.0.0.1
  localhost/127.0.0.1
  localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
  localhost/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1
getLocalHost:Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local/192.168.0.104
  /192.168.0.104
byName:/192.168.0.104
ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=63498]
time: 0
server accepting
client:/192.168.0.104:63498
time: 8
server accepted:Socket[addr=/192.168.0.104,port=63499,localport=63498]
client:Socket[addr=/192.168.0.104,port=63498,localport=63499]
time: 2
server read:123
client read:234
server closing
server done
time: 202
done
Done in 1626 ms
```

This will not solve the problem, but it will give more information about what H2 tries to do to detect the IP address.